# Correct indentation with rspec textmate bundle

Tags: rspec, textmate, textmatebundles

When I hit cmd-shift-t I see the go to symbol view for rspec, I see something like:

```
Project
  context "with collaborators"
"should have mailing list"
```

Notice that the "should have mailing list" isn't correctly indented under the context. What I'd like to see is this:

```
Project
  context "with collaborators"
    "should have mailing list"
```

I had a play with the rspec textmate grammar in the bundler editor but couldn't figure out how to change the nesting behaviour.